# example of using filter() & map() method of Stream mechanism

Tags: java, java-8

I am reading about `Stream` mechanism of java 8 and its different methods and I would like to experiment with it to map and sort string data but i couldn't be able to understand the `Stream` documentation.

from Java 8 doc of `map` method

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.
```

and the filter method,

```
Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate)
Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate.
```

can anybody gives any real-life example to use filter and map method of Stream class ?

Comment: Was Google all out of results?

Comment: The [class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) already gives an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
List<String> list= Arrays.asList("x1", "x2", "y1", "y2", "z1");
```

```
list
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("x"))
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```